# How and where to store temporary data before saving to actual DB?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-2.1

Here I want to store my data somewhere temporarily before saving to actual DB,
I looked for some articles and suggects memorycache that stores data at server site which i want to avoid,
so is there any other way to implement this in .net core?

Comment: What's wrong with memcache?

Comment: Try to explain what it is that you want to archive.  Why do you want to do this and why memcache is no an option.

Comment: Why? What the app for? What kind of data? how long? What processing? Client or server?

Comment: If you don't want to store the data in the server's memory (sessions, cache, memcache, ...) or disk (database, files, ...), then you'll have to store it at the client (hidden input fields, local storage, cookies, ...). What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Artur Cause memcache stores data  on Web Server in Application Memory

Comment: @LoztInSpace the app is very simple in which i have one form which have some fields and couple of tables, But in this tables i have to store data from other screens (can called it as child form) that should in memory and after that on my parent form i have other fields and and save button, by clicking on save button i have to push that memory data to the DB. and I am lookng for storing data at client site

Comment: Collect it in the client then save it when client is ready. 100% front end, no server code required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TempData.Peek() or TempData.Keep() to store data temporarily before saving to database.

Refer this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ansh06031982/using-tempdata-peek-and-keep-in-Asp-Net-mvc/

It is in MVC but also applicable to .NET MVC Core.

Answer (score 0):

You have several choices, all with their own advantages and disadvantages.

As has been suggested, you can keep data on the client - that's in the HTML page.
You can also keep data at the client in cookies and other client caches. This is often used for authorisation data when a user logs into a web site.

There is also Session on the server, depending on how stateless you feel.

Lastly, you can store data in SQL Server in some table that acts as a temporary store until a user posts the final data to the main table. I assume here that a user logs in and you can identify them.

Answer (score -1):

TempData may be a way to go for you.

Check [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/mvc/tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc) on how to use it.

Though I assume you have your reasons to do that. A lot better solution would be to collect all your data at the client-side and submit it in one go.